# how to say that I can't see from the fog

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

I am trying to express that when someone is smoking I can't see the things that are behind the fog because the fog is full.

I am trying to say that the fog is not like a window but it is more like a wall so when someone is smoking he/she is preventing I from seeing to behind.

I searched and I found the following:

- pellucid but I think this is more like a mirror
- thin but this is more like the against of fat
- glassy but obvious for glass
- hyaline maybe that is the word?
- diaphanous maybe that is the word?

Comment: Your words all mean "clear", "transparent".  Pellucid and Hyaline are both exceptionally rare  (this native speaker needed a dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoking produces *smoke*, or possibly a *cloud* of smoke. We don't call it fog.

To describe smoke that you *can't* see through, you could call it:

> - [thick](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/thick)
>   6. adjective
>   Thick smoke, fog, or cloud is difficult to see through.
>   *The smoke was bluish-black and thick.*
>   (Collins Dictionary)
> - [heavy](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/heavy)
>   adjective
>   2 Of great density; thick or substantial.
>   *‘heavy gray clouds’*
>   *‘The thick heavy grey smoke lingered among the branches and prevented the flowers and buds from being burned by frost.’*
>   *‘They could see an immense mountain that stretched up into heavy thick clouds.’*
>   *‘The sun was shrouded by heavy clouds that grayed the bright colors of the earth.’*
>   (Lexico)
> - [dense](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dense)
>   2. adjective
>   Dense fog or smoke is difficult to see through because it is very heavy and dark.
>   *A dense column of smoke rose several miles into the air.*
>   (Collins Dictionary)

Example sentence:

> There are so many people smoking here that I can't see past the heavy smoke!

You wouldn't typically use any of your suggested words to describe smoke, except possibly *thin*. *Thin* seems like a possible antonym for thick (see [Lexico: adj. 3.1 Not dense](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/thin) ).

Answer (score 0):

The word for things like a wall, and not like a window is "opaque".  If something is opaque, you can't see through it.

In this case I would write:

> John was hidden in a cloud of smoke.

It is easier to say this than to say "The cloud of smoke was opaque"

Answer (score 0):

The words you have listed, all mean transparent.
Words you could use are: dense, thick, heavy, opaque, solid, impenetrable, cloudy, murky, turbid, or nubilous.